# Smart group url parameter to search contributes

Tags: search, search-results, urls

I'm using CiviCRM 5.27 on Wordpress and I'd like to save Civicrm page URL of contributes with smart group filter.

I tried this:

```
http://mysite.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fcontribute%2Fsearch&reset=1&force=1&group[]=47&contribution_status_id[]=1
```

but I didn't get any filters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax doesn't use `[]` for multivalued fields. You put commas if you want more more than one. See https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/the-user-interface/searching-url-support/

So the parameters here would just be `reset=1&force=1&group=47&contribution_status_id=1`

Comment: Now I'm trying to filter by `contribution_amount_low`, so: `reset=1&force=1&group=47&contribution_amount_low=500`, but contributes are not filtered. Also the `contribution_status` parameter does not work. I'm using CiviCRM 5.28.0 on Wordpress 5.5. Not all filters can be used in url?

Comment: I have noticed not all parameters work on all screens.